# SO couldn't format the following Lisp code properly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

The following code is copied from https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/simple.el#L1347-L1358. When I copy it into the body of this question, the indentation goes wrong after line `save-excursion`. So the code below for details.

I have copied the same code into other website, but nothing appears wrong at all.

```lisp
(defun what-line ()
  "Print the current buffer line number and narrowed line number of point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (point-min))
    (n (line-number-at-pos)))
    (if (= start 1)
    (message "Line %d" n)
      (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (message "line %d (narrowed line %d)"
           (+ n (line-number-at-pos start) -1) n))))))
```

Comment: There is a {tab} character there. The line above it has 4 {space}s. Do a {tab} -> {spaces} first (in your favorite editor), then copy-paste.

Comment: @rene Indeed, it is caused by tab. I never knew such a problem exists in so. Thanks.

Comment: [Do you have a GoFundMe?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/) :-p But seriously, always use spaces.